# private method issues

Tags: ios, ruby, cordova, cucumber, appium

I am having issues with private method capabilities.

Here is a my sample env.rb file

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

#APP_PATH = 'PlainNote.app'

def capabilities
  {
      'automationName' => 'XCUITest',
      'platformName' => 'iOS',
      'deviceName' =>  'iPhone Simulator',
      'platform' => 'Mac',
      'version' => '9.2',
      'app' => '/Users/shafiq.malik/Documents/Projects/nuff-class-booking-mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloCordova.app'}
end

#def absolute_app_path
#  File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), APP_PATH)
#end

def server_url
  "http://localhost:8000/index.html"
end

def selenium
  @driver ||= Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => 
  capabilities, :url => server_url)
end

After { @driver.quit }
```

However I am getting the below error message

```
Given I load the hello world app                                 # features/step_definitions/hello_world.rb:1
  private method `capabilities' called for #<Hash:0x007fb9b07c7da8> (NoMethodError)
  ./features/support/env.rb:25:in `selenium'
```

I completely new to mobile testing. So it may be a very straight forward solution. Can somebody please be kind enough to advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: Did you try to rename `def capabilities` to `def capabilities123` and replace old name in `def selenium` with new ?

Comment: Oh wow that worked but I am not sure why? Could be kind enough to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `capabilities` as method name in that situation. 
Maybe it's defined in `Kernel` or anywhere else.

Sometimes that could happen when we use some reserved names for our needs. You could check where that method come from via `p method(:capabilities)` before your definition.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ShafiqAhmedMalik, glad to help you.